Childhood comic series involving two troublesome alien kids who get into a lot of problems
I vaguely remember this comic but I remember reading when I was in summer school on this website that only schools used. It was a series of comics that revolved around two kids, aliens to be specific.
They were very troublesome and had names like 'Zorg' and 'Zorb' or something like that. I don't remember much but I do recall the stories: one where they get stuck in a washing machine and build it into a space ship to get back home, one where they hang out in their pool on their planet (pretty sure it was summer for them) and try to get ice cream cones the fastest way possible because there was a huge line and they didn't wanna wait.
Like I said, they were very troublesome, so they got into a LOT of problems.

In roughly which year did you read this? Also, what did the aliens look like? (Hair colour, if any, skin colour, that sort of thing.)

Not really sure probably between 2015-2018 and I dont really remember any hair on them but I do think they were green besides that and don't remember much

Possibly the Whizzers from Ozz from the British comic "The Topper" - the alien kids were called Krik and Krak
https://ukcomics.fandom.com/wiki/The_Whizzers_from_Ozz

Thanks for the answer,unfortunately it's not quite it. If I'm correct I believe the comics where from the 2010s
